# combine jquery nth selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Having the following selection of table cells

```
$("table[id*=petQuoteGV] td:nth-child(2n),table[id*=petQuoteGV] td:nth-child(3n)")
```

Is it possible to make it shorter so "table[id*=petQuoteGV]" isn't repeated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) paramter of `$`:

```
$('td:nth-child(2n), td:nth-child(3n)', 'table[id*=petQuoteGV]');
```

Comment: or even further `$(':nth-child(2n), :nth-child(3n)', 'table[id*=petQuoteGV] td');`, and if this is for styling, select only the `:visible` td elements.

Comment: I don't think the updated version is right. Your (and the question's) original version applies the `:nth-child` directly to the `td`, but the updated version gets applies `:nth-child` to all descendants of the `td`.